# Weird behavior while calling async method EJB?

Tags: java, asynchronous, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, ejb

I have a weird behavior while calling asynchronous method , the method is being invoked inside a loop with two iterations . and actually it has been called two times but with last time parameters values  .however the parameters are being changed inside the loop .

```
Example : 
first iteration : tenant_id=11 
second iteration :tenant_d=10
```

while debugging the async function the two times invocation parameters values were 10 !!

the async function :

```
@Stateless
public class StatisticsMigrator {
    @Asynchronous
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void doMigrate(final ConnectionParameters params) {
    LOG.debug("migration has been started in asynchronous mode);
    }
}


@Path("{/endpoint}")
public class WebService
{
    @Inject
    StatisticsMigrator migrator;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/general/")
    public Response migrate(@Context final HttpHeaders 
     argHeaders)
    {
        ConnectionParameters par=ConnectionParameters.creatConnectionParamsObject(baseUri, argHeaders.getHeaderString("Authorization"),tenantId);

        for (Tenant tenant : tenants) {
            par.setTenantId(String.valueOf(tenant.getRetailerId()));
            migrator.doMigrate(par);
      }
    }

}
```

Comment: You pass the same object twice to the method, and this method is invoked later, asynchronously. So at the time it's actually invoked, the two invocations receive the same object, in the same, latest state. You'd better use immutable objects when calling asynchronous methods (since the object is accessed from two threads), and you should thus create two separate immutable instances.

Comment: @JBNizet you are right the problem was with the second thread override the first one values .
but actually i did not expect that it will run into multithreading mode specially from the ejb documentation that   managing threads from EJBs is disallowed because it would harm resource management, transaction management, security . can you explain that ?

Comment: You're not creating and starting a thread by yourself when calling an async method. The container deals with threads for you. And even if the two method invocations are executed by the same async thread, they're executed after the for loop has ended.